# How to swap text between double quotes using EXCEL formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to swap text between double quotes in EXCEL single cell.

```
Example Text:  {"TEST1", "METHOD"},

Expected Result: {"METHOD", "TEST1"},
```

Tried this function but it doesn't work.

```
=right(A1,len(A1)-find(" ",A1))&" "&left(A1,find(",",A1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
="{"&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-FIND(",",A1)-2)&", "&MID(A1,2,FIND(",",A1)-2)&"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter formula option

```
="{"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1&A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-2),"}{",", ")&"}"
```